# Teams confusing complaint: "Real Name is required because you are a member of a Team"

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

I entered Stack Overflow Teams (with my company account, not this one) and wanted to change my profile. Trying to Save the changes, I get the message:

> Real Name is required because you are a member of a Team

On that whole page, I don't see a field "Real Name". The one that comes close is "Display Name", though this one **is** and was filled out before and this was not the bit I wanted to change.

Even if this is the field in error, what then my "Real Name" according to Stack Overflow's logic?

Comment: I think it is Full Name at the bottom of your profile settings?

Comment: Your real name is the one that appears on your birth certificate / driver’s license / password, whatever. My display name happens to be my real name, for example. I don’t know how to fix the error you’re seeing, but I can point out the motivation: on Teams, you should be a known, trusted entity, so pseudonymity is not permitted.

Comment: Error message is too cryptic - personally I find this not user friendly and sort of buggy.  Should be a link to additional help rather than a single sentence error message?

Comment: @DanBron well, some people have different names appearing on birth certificate, passport and company contract (examples: romanization of the name, marriage, witness protection, ...), so that makes potentially multiple real names.

Comment: @Cœur I’m sure. The world loves nothing more than a corner case for we poor bedraggled programmers. I think a good heuristic would be “what your colleagues (who work on your Team) believe your official name to be”. That will usually correlate with the name on your company contract or email address. But yes, there are always corner cases.....

Comment: Also, note that requiring a real name online is illegal in Germany: https://www.theverge.com/2018/2/12/17005746/facebook-real-name-policy-illegal-german-court-rules

Comment: Also, interesting readings: [designing an HTML form for personal names](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names.en) and [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: @DanBron it seems odd for SE to be the one trying/caring to enforce it... I've got a couple coworkers with "silly"/pseudoanonymous github user names, but if my manager cared then he'd talk to them, not to github.

Comment: @mbrig I feel the same, but there may be regulations, constraints, or user research we're not privvy to.  Worth another Meta-Q, perhaps.  But I was just trying to lay out my understanding of what the rule *is* for OP, who is asking about that. I don't have any insight into the *why* of the rule, myself.

Comment: @DanBron No. When an *error message* names some piece of data, it means *what the software defines it to mean*. Since the software is not going out and verifying your birth certificate or any of the other things you mention, that is completely irrelevant to whatever the software is indicating you need to do. Most likely, "Real Name" refers to some particular field that it believes has been left empty and you could put "Thisisnot myrealname" or any other text in it to satisfy its requirements. The trouble here is that either the UI is not clearly indicating which field to fill or there's a bug.

Comment: @Cœur I prefer [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Falsehoods Lists](https://kevin.deldycke.com/2016/12/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-falsehoods-lists/).

Comment: @cpburnz that domain has an expired certificate.

Comment: @DanBron I work at a company that tried teams.  We also have slack and a half dozen other apps-  all of where we use screen names, none of us use our real names (or even the names we call each other) on it.;  I can understand a company deciding to add that requirement, I see no reason why SO should do so.  While that wasn't the reason it failed at my workplace, it would be a turnoff for some of my coworkers.

Comment: @DanBron Also while my coworkers may know who I am, and while may have made a conscience decision to give that info to SO (based on my username)-  many of my coworkers may not want to give personal information to some tool because somebody decided to test it.

Comment: @GabeSechan Guys, I don’t know why you’re directing these comments at me. I am not the one asking for you real names. I have no use for them and no interest in them. I just responded to OP who asked what was meant by that term.

Answer (score 11):

As @rene pointed out, it was indeed the Full Name at the bottom of the page. Due to the error message I was more or less sure it must have something to do with the Display Name to be not a silly alias in the teams context and did not even think about this other field.

Likely the error message and the field name should agree on the wording to make this clearer.